# why does gdb increment memory addresses in units of 10

Tags: c, gdb

I'm trying to understand why gdb shows memory addresses in increments of 10[hex].
I have compiled my c program with `-m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector` flags and turned of ASLR.

When I debug my program, it shows me the following
[image]

When I attempt to query the next address it appears to cycle through the bytes

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding this behavior of gdb.

Furthermore, if I create a `char buf[n]` size of `n` in my c program I can't accurately count the space used by buf while debugging, I'm wondering how the cycling effect plays into this as well.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you ask. But it's actually 10 in hex, which is 16 in decimal.

Comment: It's actually 16 (10 hex) - my guess it's just what would fit on a line.

Comment: true, my bad, but its still incrementing by 16 which I don't understand. Also, why does it cycle through the same data?

Comment: If you start reading a 32 bit value at address 0x00000000 and then start reading a 32 bit value from address 0x00000001 then 3 of the 4 bytes you read in the first case will also be present in the second case.

Comment: As you can see, it's showing 4 x 4-byte units on each line - therefore the next line is 16 (0x10) bytes later.

Comment: Reading a 32-bit value with a non 32-bit offset (4 byte) is likely a mistake.

Comment: I  see, in terms of calculating the allocation for `buf[n]` how would that work in a non 32 bit increment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are confused by [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (of 32-bit integers):

In memory the first 8 bytes are

```
0x54ffffc5 -> c5 ff ff 54
0x54ffffc5 -> c5 ff ff 54
```

so if you step one byte in memory you will find

```
<skip first byte> ff ff 54 c5 ff ff 54 ...
```

so you see (as 32-bit integer)

```
ff ff 54 c5 -> 0xc554ffff
```